# How does one increase Vds in Transistors technically speaking?

Tags: transistors

[image]

I tried to google my question but I found no answer. Obviously the voltage at the drain is increased. But I'm actually interested how this solution is technically implemented.

Comment: Do you mean how is a transistor constructed with higher \$V_{DSmax}\$?

Comment: The voltage stress is lateral. Obviously, increasing the distance helps with stand-off and perhaps also with heat dissipation that follows the idea. But different planer edge termination structures are almost always needed, as well. Simulation is needed to "do the numbers" on that. There are three common single-zone ones I've read about before. But fabrication processing and its inherent deviations have to be taken into account in choosing. Different processing helps, such as SiC, for example. Etc. Lots of stuff on the topics. I've never taken a class in electronics and I've found this much.